# Log in to Heroku via bash script

Tags: bash, heroku, authentication

I try to write a script in which I call some command from heroku toolbelt. Script works fine till I am login to heroku toolbelt. When I've tried to add heroku's login command during script execution I occured some problems - there is no in heroku toolbelt command such as (command with parameters):

```
heroku login -u email@mail.com -p 1234qwer
```

That why I have no idea how to execute heroku login command in bash script. Has anyone got some advice?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For these kinds of things I use expect.

You need to install `expect` first. If you're on Ubuntu run `sudo apt-get install expect`

Then in a script, let's call it heroku_login.exp, enter this with the relevant information:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn heroku "login"

expect "Email:"

send "YOUREMAIL";

send "\r"

expect "Password (typing will be hidden):"

send "YOURPASSWORD"

send "\r"

interact
```

Then run `expect heroku_login.exp` and you should be good to go.

Comment: I tried on mac. For some reason, it stuck after password is entered. (didn't run enter after expect fill the password)

Answer (score 2):

An easier solution to this problem may be to just set the `HEROKU_API_KEY` environment variable. The Heroku toolbelt will then automatically log you in using that key.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work anymore. I've also tried interpolating environment variables (api key and email) in ~/.netrc and have had mixed luck with that approach - it works ~50% of the time.