# Heroku Login Bash Script

Tags: bash, heroku

Im trying to automate the login action of the Heroku CLI.
I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29312116/12405213) but Im not using Ubuntu (Windows) and it looks like expect is only usable in Ubuntu.

I have: `echo -ne "email@example.com\nsecurePassword123\n" | heroku login -i`

But this is not working [properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLcWV.png).

Comment: Heroku offers an API for automation. You should consider using that instead.

Comment: I don't want to use the tokens though. :(

Comment: Why not? That might help folks point you in a better direction.

Comment: Because I want to use it on new accounts